# How can i retrieve the current form in this context

Tags: jquery, forms

I would like to know how to access the $(this) for this particular form element once the post request has been made. I'm a little unclear about the scope here.

Appreciate anyone's eye with this!

Cheers

code here:

```
 $('form', document).on('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var self = $(this);
    $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');

    var temp_url = $(this).find(".web_url");
    var lasturl;
    $.each(temp_url,function(key,object){
        if(key==(temp_url.length-1))
        {
            lasturl = object.value;
        }
    });

    var temp_wdth = $(this).find(".width");
    var lastwdth;
    $.each(temp_wdth,function(key,object){
        if(key==(temp_wdth.length-1))
        {
            lastwdth = object.value;
        }
    });

    var temp_hgth = $(this).find(".height");
    var last_hgth;
    $.each(temp_hgth,function(key,object){
        if(key==(temp_hgth.length-1))
        {
            last_hgth = object.value;
        }
    });

    var weburl = lasturl;
    var width = lastwdth;
    var height = last_hgth;
    var dee = <?php echo $deet[0]->id; ?>;


    $.post( "mde", { weburl: weburl, width: width, height: height, dee: dee })
      .done(function( data ) {
         u = data;
         if (u == 'url not set')
         {
            alert(u);
         }
         else
         {
            self.hide();
            console.log(u);
            $.get(u);

         }

    });
});
```

Comment: Just do `var self = this;` at the top, and use it anywhere ?

Comment: This: `$(document,'form')` should be: `$('form', document)` or `$('form')`. _$(selector, context)_

Comment: Then, `$(this)` will return the current `form` in your context.

Comment: edited the code to reflect what i'm now doing. I cannot seem to get the form to hide though.

Comment: Some other tips: To find the first in a collection of elements `$(this).find(your-selector).first()` and the last `$(this).find(your-selector).last()`. You don't need to loop through and test to get the one you want.

Comment: Try with the code in this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/Lfpjygru/1/ Also, it would be interesting if you include your HTML markup in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy option is adding 'var self = this' at the top. However, that is a hack ignoring javascript's built in context functionality. A better option would be to use javascript as it was intended to be used and implement a .bind() on the anonymous function in the $.post().

When creating a function, you can explicitly tell javascript what context to run it in using .bind().

Here is an example. Suppose we had an object saved to the variable bob. It has a key, 'name', with the value of "Bob".

`bob = {name: "Bob"}`

We want to make a function that return's bob's name. So we can create a function that returns 'this.name' and bind it to the bob object.

```
function introduceBob(){
  return this.name
}.bind(bob)
```

By binding it to bob, the function is going to execute as though it were part of the bob object. Any occurrence of 'this' will refer to that object. When we call `introduceBob()`, it will return `'Bob'`.

In your situation, we want to maintain the current context as we delve into that anonymous function. In other words, we want 'this' in that anonymous function to refer to the same object as the 'this' in the .on() function. To do that, you can change this code:

```
    $.post( "mde", { weburl: weburl, width: width, height: height, dee: dee })
      .done(function( data ) {
         u = data;
         if (u == 'url not set')
         {
            alert(u);
         }
         else
         {
            console.log(u);
            $.get(u);
         }
    });
```

To this code:

```
    $.post( "mde", { weburl: weburl, width: width, height: height, dee: dee })
      .done(function( data ) {
         u = data;
         if (u == 'url not set')
         {
            alert(u);
         }
         else
         {
            console.log(u);
            $.get(u);

         }

    }.bind(this));
```

Simple change, right? Now 'this' inside of the anonymous function will use the same context as 'this' in the rest of the .on() function.

Note: You will still need to jQuery select 'this' in order to call jQuery methods on it.

Additional resources on .bind(), context and/or scope:

[.bind() on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).
[Ryan Morr's Understanding Scope and Context in Javascript](http://ryanmorr.com/understanding-scope-and-context-in-javascript/)